# RichTextBox in Xaml + InlineUIContainer

Tags: c#, wpf

Given the following Xaml, why does the RichTextBox at 100,150 have the 123 misaligned? You'll notice that in the same RichTextBox, if I inline text directly as a TextBlock, then it remains aligned with the normal runs. If I put it inside of a ContentPresenter it gets all wacky.

I tried playing around with padding and margins, but can't get it lined up.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Test">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Abc;123" Margin="100,100,0,0" />
        <RichTextBox>
            <RichTextBox.Document>
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run>Abc</Run>
                        <Run>;</Run>
                        <Run>123</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox.Document>
        </RichTextBox>
        <ContentPresenter Content="Abc;123" Margin="100,120,0,0" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Test}" />

        <RichTextBox Margin="100,150,0,0">
            <RichTextBox.Document>
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <InlineUIContainer>
                            <TextBlock Text="Abc" />
                        </InlineUIContainer>
                        <Run>;</Run>
                        <InlineUIContainer>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="123" />
                        </InlineUIContainer>
                    </Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox.Document>
        </RichTextBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `InlineUIContainer.BaselineAlignment` to "Center" for `ContentPresenter`.

```
<InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Center">
    <ContentPresenter Content="123" />
</InlineUIContainer>
```